# What does it mean to "squeal on someone"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does it mean?

> He can't squeal on him.

Answer (score 2):

From American Heritage Dictionary via [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/squeal):

> **squeal** *Slang* To turn informer; betray an
>   accomplice or secret.

Here's some synonyms from *The New Oxford American*:

> inform on, tell tales on; report, give away, be disloyal to, sell out, stab in the back; *informal* rat on, rat out, snitch on, put the finger on, finger, [sell down the river](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11111/5822).

You can find some good examples of it in use at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/squeal%20on/examples).

Answer (score 1):

It started off as criminal argot, but has worked its way into the general vocabulary to mean anyone who "tells" on someone for doing something "wrong". A sister can squeal on her broother, a student can squeal on another student, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

"Squealing on someone" is a colloquial expression meaning to inform the police of someone's illegal activities.

Comment: Does it have to be illegal or can it be used for simpler examples, like for example, squealing to the parents about what your brother did?

Comment: @fifo: You are correct